# Apply SlideUp transition on .removeClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, slideup

Trying to apply SlideUp transition while `.removeClass` . This script show/hide navigation menu on page scroll Up/down. I want to add transition when navigation menu hide.
See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fbr320y/1/) >

**JS**

```
lastScroll = 0;
$(window).on('scroll',function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll === 0){
        $(".nav").removeClass("darkHeader");
    } else if(lastScroll - scroll > 0) {
        $(".nav").addClass("darkHeader");
    } else {
        $(".nav").removeClass("darkHeader");
    }
    lastScroll = scroll;
});
```

I Tried:

```
lastScroll = 0;
    $(window).on('scroll',function() {    
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(scroll === 0){
            $(".nav").removeClass("darkHeader");
        } else if(lastScroll - scroll > 0) {
            $(".nav").addClass("darkHeader");
        } else {
            $(".nav").removeClass("darkHeader").slideUp("1000"); //I have Added
        }
        lastScroll = scroll;
    });
```

It's not works. Question is how add `slideUp` effect while Navigation hide?
I'm trying to do Like [This](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Hide-Sticky-Navbar-When-Scrolling-Down-Scroll-Up-Menu) >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can use [slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/) & [slideDown()](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/) functions like below :

```
$(window).on('scroll',function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll === 0){
        $(".nav").removeClass("darkHeader");
    } else if(lastScroll - scroll > 0) {
        if(!$(".nav").hasClass('darkHeader')) $(".nav").hide();

        $(".nav").slideDown('fast',function(){
            $(".nav").addClass("darkHeader");
        });
    } else {
        $(".nav.darkHeader").slideUp('slow',function(){
            $(".nav").removeClass("darkHeader");
        });
    }
    lastScroll = scroll;
});
```

See your example working with the 2 functions here : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9fbr320y/15/)